# Gradle sync failed causing 'Preview is unavailable until after a successful build project sync'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to open a very old android app because I need to upgrade it.
I updated the Gradle plugin, the Gradle and also the SDK tools and the project is compiling and running on my device.

The problem is that I can't use the Preview window of my XML files and I keep getting this Error -

> Gradle sync failed: EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false >Toolkit.getEventQueue()=com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue@15b8713b
>             Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread >19,4,Idea Thread Group] 1926886061
>             SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,Idea >Thread Group] 686233834 (905 ms)

I've tried to clean and rebuild the project, tried to invalidate cache and restart and even restart the computer because I thought that one thread is lose...

Is someone encountered this problem?

**UPDATE:**

Problem solved.

I had a declaration of **minSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** both in the Manifest and Gradle. 
Deleting it from the Manifest fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

```xml
This is a common problem. It can be easily solved by changing res/values/styles.xml to

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
Steps :
Go to res/values/
open styles.xml

change from -> style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

change to -> style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

    (Just prepend "Base." to "Theme".)



Save the file and check Preview now.

Preview Works Perfectly now.
```

Comment: still the same :\

Answer (score -1):

Can you try once deleting .gradle folder? This might solve the problem I suppose.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer!